# Issue occurring while invoking the browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-8, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I am getting the following error :

Error: Unable to initialize main class SeleniumClass
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ‘void sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.initIDs()’

The environment details are:

1. Selenium 3 ( occurring on 4 too)
2. JDK 8
3. Browser: Chrome 88, Firefox 85, Edge 88
4. Windows 64

The Selenium webdriver are compatible with the version of browsers.
The normal JAVA code is working fine on eclipse and getting output on console. The observation is that issue is occurring while invoking the browser.

Below is the code snippet:

```
System.setProperty(“webdriver.chrome.driver”,”C:\\Work\\chromedriver.exe”);
System.setProperty(“webdriver.gecko.driver”,”C:\\Work\\geckodriver.exe”);
System.setProperty(“webdriver.edge.driver”,”C:\\Work\\msedgedriver.exe”);
WebDriver driver1= new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver driver2= new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver3= new EdgeDriver();
```

I put a breakpoint on System.setProperty and run the program on debug mode, then the below error has occurred:-

******ERROR: This jdwp native library will not work with this VM's version of JVMTI (15.0.0), it needs JVMTI 1.2[.1].»´ù~ù******